# Nhibernate join with select columns from both tables

Tags: nhibernate, select, join, queryover

Ok after several attempts I am stuck on this one!

I am using NHibernate with QueryOver as below. I have a Product and ProductReview as

```
public class Product
{
 ....
 public virtual IList<ProductReview> CustomerReviews {get;set;}
 ....
}

public class ProductReview
{
 ....
 public virtual Product Product {get;set;}
 ....
}
```

Mapping on Product side is

```
HasMany(x => x.CustomerReviews).KeyColumn("ProductId").Inverse().Cascade.None().LazyLoad();
```

The Query is

```
 Product px = null;
 ProductReview rev = null;
var result = CurrentSession
            .QueryOver<ProductReview>()
            .Where(r => r.IsActive && !r.IsDraft)
            .Select(
                Projections.Property<ProductReview>(r => r.Id).WithAlias(() => rev.Id),
                Projections.Property<ProductReview>(r => r.Title).WithAlias(() => rev.Title)
                )
            .OrderBy(r => r.ReviewDate).Desc()
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ProductReview>())
            .JoinAlias(r => r.Product, () => px)
            .Select(
               Projections.Property(() => px.UPC).WithAlias(() => px.UPC),
               Projections.Property(() => px.FullName).WithAlias(() => px.FullName)
              )
              .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Product>())
              .Take(5)
              .List();
```

The error is:
The value "Reviews.Models.Product" is not of type "Reviews.Models.ProductReview" and cannot be used in this generic collection. Parameter name: value

I really do not want to create another DTO. I would like to get the list of Last 5 new reviews and have it's Product populated (only a few required fields on both entities should be filled).

Is this possible by any means (except raw sql) in NHibernate 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Product px = null;
ProductReview rev = null;

var result = CurrentSession.QueryOver<ProductReview>()
    .Where(r => r.IsActive && !r.IsDraft)
    .JoinQueryOver(r => r.Product)
    .OrderBy(r => r.ReviewDate).Desc()
    .Take(5)
    .List();
```

Comment: I did mention that I didn't want another DTO class. But thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: Updated my answer to remove the DTO.

Comment: That is whant I am using now but it pulls all the fields of each entitiy which is an overkill for me.

Comment: You need to accept the fact you are using an ORM. You are breaking principles by requiring only partial data to be returned.